# Android Espresso click a button inside a ListView

Tags: java, android, android-espresso

I'm trying to make a test with Espresso that performs a click on a button within a specific element of my Listview.

Each element in the ListView has a a button (R.id.my_button) and I want to click the button of the first element.

I tried:
        onData(anything()).
                atPosition(0).
                inAdapterView(
                        allOf(
                                withId(R.id.my_button)
                        )
                ).
                perform(click());

Actual result:
androidx.test.espresso.AmbiguousViewMatcherException: '(with id: com.test.test:id/my_button)' matches multiple views in the hierarchy.

Answer (score 2):

This might help, 
Go inside listView -> first element -> first element's child (in your case the button)

```
onData(anything()).inAdapterView(withId(R.id.list)).atPosition(0).onChildView(withId(R.id.my_button)).check(matches(isDisplayed())).perform(click());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go inside AdapterView, this will allow you to click an element inside listview

```
onData(anything()).inAdapterView(withId(R.id.list1)).atPosition(0).perform(click());
```

Comment: Thanks and sorry if I was not clear. I don't want to click on an item of the ListView. I want to click on a button (R.id.my_button) that is inside the View of each element of the listView[   [elem_1:View{my_button,my_image,...}][elem_2:View{my_button,my_image,..]. ]